# Amazon EC2 wordpress permalinks not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I am trying to apply permalinks on my website.
when i try to change for a different page i get direct to the home page again.

I checked the httpd config :

```
<Directory "/var/www">
   Options  FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and its look ok.
also i checked my htaccess file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and its also look fine.
 I checked the files and folders permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 14028 Nov  5 11:51 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   418 Nov  5 11:31 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 19935 Nov  5 11:31 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  7109 Nov  5 11:34 readme.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  5447 Nov  5 11:34 wp-activate.php
drwxrwsr-x  9 apache apache  4096 Nov  5 11:31 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   364 Nov  5 11:34 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  1627 Nov  5 11:34 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  3472 Nov  5 11:48 wp-config.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  2853 Nov  5 11:34 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwsr-x  5 apache apache  4096 Nov  5 11:31 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  3286 Nov  5 11:34 wp-cron.php
drwxrwsr-x 18 apache apache 12288 Nov  5 11:34 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  2422 Nov  5 11:34 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  3301 Nov  5 11:34 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 34327 Nov  5 11:34 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  8048 Nov  5 11:34 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 16200 Nov  5 11:34 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 29924 Nov  5 11:34 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  4513 Nov  5 11:34 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  3065 Nov  5 11:34 xmlrpc.php
```

and its all look fine.

When installing a new site its work fine. but when i install some plugin, it does not matter which. its stop working.

The only thing I get in the network is error 301

**EDIT**

I found out that if changed the "Front Page Display" on the reading setting from static page to latest update its work.
but I do not think it's the right way.

Does anyone understand why it works this way and not with static page?
It may be something related to the definition of the page?

Comment: I think you are not giving enough information. What kind of error you get?

Comment: @DanieleFois in the network i see 301

Comment: can you include the error in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I tried to add a function that would disable the API and it caused the problem.
I deleted the function and it works!